# Fuzzy section on laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display

Unfortunately, I dropped my laptop and cracked the back of the hinge. Now, my laptop screen often has a section become fuzzy on startup:

[image]

It is a bit hard to see on the image due to reflections, but I have issues in a nearly perfectly rectangular section. This fuzziness mainly occurs on startup, but after a while will completely disappear. If my laptop screen turns off for a short time, the fuzziness will normally come back, but it should be easier to get it working again than if it were off for a long time.

I know I'll have to get it serviced, but does anyone know what is actually happening? For example, why does it start working after a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a hairline fracture in the circuitry.  When the screen warms up the expansion of the components causes the fracture to close up.  When it cools again the fracture opens up again.

Comment: Could it be something more serious if it happens to the entirety ofmy screen? It just did tonight. I shut it down via holding down the power button then powered it back on several minutes later. The screen is clear after that.